# Huawei DRM SDK gives RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, drm, appgallery-connect

I have and app published on Huawei AppGallery. The application is paid and is protected by the huawei DRM SDK, and everything was working fine even the huawei DRM SDK.

But I now wanted to launch a new version of the application, but I get this error:

`2020-06-19 15:11:16.797 17128-17128/com.aquainfo.huawei E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aquainfo.huawei, PID: 17128
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aquainfo.huawei/com.huawei.android.sdk.drm.DrmDialogActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:430)
        at android.content.res.HwResources.getText(HwResources.java:463)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:523)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:582)
        at com.huawei.android.sdk.drm.j.a(Unknown Source:124)
        at com.huawei.android.sdk.drm.DrmDialogActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:143)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)`

Based on this line `com.huawei.android.sdk.drm.DrmDialogActivity}` I think that the problem is with the huawei SDK, but so far it was working well with the DRM SDK.

My DRM sdk version is the 2.5.2.300. Is there somthing happening with that SDK? Ore hase the version chaged?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by your resource files not found.

Verify that the resource files in .res file in DRM SDK folder are correctly imported, and not mistakenly deleted. Import them again if necessary.

For details, visit the official document [DRM Service](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-paidapps-agcprepare-0000001074231614#section157071017101619).

Comment: Thank you very much, it saved my day. The strings in the Huawei DRM SDK had disappeared without me knowing why.